# How to design a table, where the values of one column may come from either of two other tables in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am trying to implement the following in a SQL database:

I have three tables.

```
CREATE TABLE company1(
    id int NOT NULL,
    prod_id int NOT NULL,
    company1_quality_value int)

CREATE TABLE company2(
    id int NOT NULL,
    prod_id int NOT NULL,
    company2_quality_value int)

CREATE TABLE production(
    id int NOT NULL,
    prod_id int NOT NULL,
    corrected_quality_value int)
```

Suppose two companies calculate some quality value for a product and I store this in two separate tables. Now also suppose that I want to make a production table for this product, with a column `corrected_quality_value`. Since I trust `company2` more than `company1`, I would like this column to be `company2_quality_value` whenever `company2` has the value stored for the specific product ID `prod_id`. However, this value may be `NULL`. Only in this case I will take the value `company1_quality_value`, which we can suppose will always exist.

My question is: should I try and design the relationship between these values from the get go (and if so, how would I do it best) or should I just do it in the backend and leave the values without a relationship.

The second option just seems odd, since in my mind this would create at least some data duplication (since the values in `corrected_quality_value` are already stored somewhere else).

Comment: If you tend to access information from company2 more frequently than infos from company1, having two tables will avoid you making additional filtering operations.

Comment: Drop derived data from your tables. Create views returning derived data.

Comment: As you are finding out, that is not a good schema design.  Instead, have only one table for all companies.